# What units does canvas.drawImage() use when specifying position and dimensions?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas with a percentage width and height, and I am drawing an image in there.

I would like to draw the image with 50% width, and 100% height of the canvas. How do I accomplish this?

Here's some code:

```
#canvas {
     width: 100%;
     height: 33%;
}

var cv = document.getElementById('canvas');
var cx = cv.getContext('2d');

var bg = document.createElement('img');
bg.src = bg_url;

cx.drawImage(bg, ?, ?, ?, ?);
// cx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, 50%, 100%); essentially

// now let's draw that second image at 50% of the canvas (tiling)

cx.drawImage(bg, ?, ?, ?, ?);
// cx.drawImage(bg, 50%, 0, 50%, 100%); essentially
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What units does canvas.drawImage() use when specifying position and dimensions?

It uses `CSS pixels` for all its dimensions.

This:

```
#canvas {
     width: 100%;
     height: 33%;
}
```

will just scale the canvas as an image. The canvas pixel dimension will remain the same just resulting in a lower quality result. As a thum-of-rule always set absolute size on the canvas element (if you don't the size will always be 300 x 150 pixels no matter what you set with CSS).

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasID');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;        // use the target size instead if
canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 33; // not the window
```

And then:

```
cx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height);
```

Comment: So if I have a dynamic width/height canvas, I would have to use JS to generate the position for me?

Comment: @ShanePhelps that's correct (unless you want the content to stretch of course). But everything you need to draw to canvas need to be done with JS so this is only a couple of lines extra.

Comment: I think I got it. So, if the canvas was set to 100px x 100px, but scaled it to the full width of the page, then drew an image starting at 50 for x, it would start it smack dab in the middle?

Comment: @ShanePhelps exactly so :) (it would start in the middle)